# Fragment lifecycle priority

Tags: android

Hey when multiple fragments are add to an activity is

```
onActivityCreate(Bundle bundle);
```

always called in the order the fragments are added? Looks like this is true but i can't find any documentation to support it

Comment: Look in to the source, you find there what you seek.

Comment: IMHO, what you are seeking suggests a serious code smell. Neither the activity, nor any fragment, should care about the order in which fragments are called with lifecycle methods. This is particularly true with configuration changes, when you are not responsible for the creation of those fragments.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee the activities will be created in order, as they are created when the Android feels like it's a good time to create them. However, if you are not doing any significant processing between when you add the fragment and when they show up, it's safe to assume they will be added in order.

If you need to base some processing off of the order the fragments are adding, consider using a static variable that gets incremented each time `onActivityCreated()` is called or similar.

Comment: "it's safe to assume they will be added in order" -- I certainly would not assume that. That behavior is not documented and would depend on internal implementation.

Comment: @CommonsWare Following the stack trace of `onActivityCreated()` shows that the activity is being created via the main thread message handler. Since the handler operates on a queue of messages, we can assume that as long as the messages are queued in order that they will be processed in order. However, I am not sure how or when the messages are added to the queue.